# Why did my mouse/trackpad suddenly stop working on my MacBook under Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, mouse, macbook, boot-camp

My mouse and track pad have suddenly stopped working on my MacBook, which is running Windows XP from BootCamp. Both the USB mouse and the trackpad work fine in OS X.

The device manager says that the driver is missing or corrupt on both items (they have a yellow exclamation point). I tried uninstalling the mice, and reinstalling them. Since the USB mouse is a Logitech I tried replacing the driver with one downloaded from Logitech.com.

Anyone know how I can repair the mouse driver that Windows XP is using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that for some reason the problem started after installing Kaspersky, and uninstalling that anti-virus software restored the mouse functionality. Strange.

Answer (score 1):

I would go ahead and reinstall the official bootcamp drivers and then see if it still give you issues. You shouldn't need to modify or change a simple driver such as the mouse and trackpad.